# How can I run a gulp task globally

Tags: node.js, gulp

Good day people,

I have a gulpfile.js with a few tasks inside it that I would like to run (from the command line) globally on my system. Is this possible? If yes, how exactly would/should I go about doing this?

Essentially, what I am really trying to do is to create an installable node command line tool that utilizes the tasks that I have already set up in gulp.

Looking forward to reading your responses.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure this isn't possible. This is because gulp looks for a local gulp installation and a local file. Maybe there could be an ugly hack.

Instead write a module yourself which maybe uses [commander](https://www.npmjs.com/package/commander) to get CLI functionality. If you'd want to you could then call gulp tasks from within your module.